# Relationship student, teacher and school unexplained

Tags: mysql, database

There are three entities:

```
School, teacher and student
```

There are some rules:

- A student can belong to one teacher only
- A student can belong to one school only
- A teacher can belong to one or more schools

This mean that I've those relations in my tables:

- The table students has a link to teacher and one to school
- The table teacher has a linking table with school (many to many relationship)

Now this is the problem. Suppose to have the following situation

```
School A    school B
 | |____       |
 |     |       |
 |    Teacher John
 |     |
 |     |
Student Ale
```

As you can see the teacher John is connected to two schools and the student Ale to the teacher John and the school A.

Now the teacher John leave the school A, but the student Ale remains linked to the teacher John that now belong only to the school B. The fact is that Ale is not going to the school B so he should be disconnected by the teacher John in this case.

I'm trying to do all this programmatically, but I've the suspect there is something wrong in the schema. Can you spot anything wrong with it?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And I'd also say you've got some normalisation issues with your database design.

Comment: Why not have a `CLASS` table which belongs to the school and students belong to the `CLASS`. The `CLASS` also has a `Teacher`. That way you can reassign teachers to classes without having to go though the students.

Comment: can teacher belong to school even if he doesnt have any student from school?

Comment: yes, he can belong to the school, but not have any teacher assigned at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Db expert, but if i were you i would sole this like that:

```
Teacher*--------1 teachesIn 1------------*School
                        *                   *
                        |                   |
                        |                   |
                        1                   |
                      Student 1--------------
```

so your student is not linked to teacher itself but to link table between teacher and school,
so if teacher stops teaching in school, automatically you remove relation between teacher and student

Comment: This is a good solution. Also, since the relation between school and teacher is many to many, you need the relation table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You've stated that you're linking your `students` directly to the school. Within SQL, you can make sure that only `teachers` are valid which also have this school.

In SQL, this can be achieved with for example `INNER JOIN`. When Teacher John leaves School A, Student Ale either MUST get a new teacher or the entry for Student Ale is no longer valid (and won't be shown when using `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

Logically you should set the condition that:
a student can belong only to one teacher who belongs to the student's school

before assignments you can check if this condition is true or not..

And when a teacher updates his schools you should check student-teacher assignment again.